# Is there a way to attach a CKFinder to the CKEditor available in PrimeFaces extension?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ckeditor, ckfinder, primefaces-extensions

I don't use the [editor](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/editor.xhtml) provided by Primefaces. Instead, I'm using [PrimeFaces](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/primefaces/extensions/primefaces-extensions/) [extensions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cprimefaces-extensions) for [CKEditor](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/basicUsage.jsf). There is no CKFinder to browse files in CKEditor in PrimeFaces extension.

Can we attach a CKFinder to this CKEditor like the one shown [here](http://ckeditor.com/demo)?

Comment: `CkFinder` is not a opensource as `CKEditor`. It's a commercial product and you need buy licence for that. Long time ago when we got conflict like that we integrated with `FCKEditor` which has all `CKEditor+CKFinder` features for free. But not sure `FCKEditor` still exists

Comment: I used a CKEditor along with a CKFinder in JSP and PHP about a year ago. Can't we make such an external CKFinder work with the CKEditor provided by PrimeFaces extension?